# Install game on another PC using the CD key from Steam?

Tags: steam, magicka

About 3 years ago I wanted to buy a game called "Magicka" from Steam. But due to some weird issues I couldn't proceed and pay. After waiting serveal hours and restarting the PC a couple of times, I gave up and created a new Steam account on which it worked just fine.
Lately I bought Magicka including 21 DLCs and registered it to my main Steam account.
Now I still have the normal Magicka on the second account I created years ago and I'm wondering if I couldn't just take the CD key and give it to a friend, sothat he could install it on his computer. 
Would that be possible? What would he need? A retail disc?

Comment: Usually steam keys ONLY work with steam. You could give him the login to that other account though

Comment: The CD Key listed on Magicka is only for a forums badge paradox plaza.

Answer (score 5):

You can't give away a Steam game license, they are account-bound. You can, however, use [Steam Family Sharing](http://store.steampowered.com/sharing/) to let other people play your games when you aren't playing (or when either of you is in offline mode, wink-wink nudge-nudge). Family Sharing is currently in closed beta, so you'll need to wait to get access or for it to become public for an undetermined period of time, though.

Comment: Sorry for asking a year and a half later, hopefully you're still around. But if we use the offline mode trick thingy, what about cloud saves?

Comment: @NealC they aren't going to get synced until you go online, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Once a key is redeemed on Steam, it is permanently assigned to that account. It is in no way, shape or form transferable.

It is possible to trade games if they have not been activated on one's Steam account, however. If you purchase a game, you have an option to add it to your Steam Inventory (not your Library). When the game is in your inventory, you cannot play it; you can however add it to your Library (but it's then permanently yours), or you can trade it to someone else.